# Printing randomly fed values from an ArrayList in Java

Tags: java, sorting, search, random, arraylist

I am processing elements of an `ArrayList` in random order, generally by printing them out. I would like to detect when the randomly selected index is `0` or `1` so as to perform special handling for those cases, where the handling for index `0` is partially dependent on whether index `1` has previously been processed.  Specifically, nothing is immediately printed when index `1` is processed, but if it is processed then when index `0` is subsequently processed, both the index `1` and the index `0` values are printed.  In any event, the loop is exited after ten iterations or after processing index `0`, whichever comes first.

I tried to implement this using `if` statements, but there where obvious flaws with that one.  I have searched everywhere for any examples but found none.  I have begun to consider using sorting algorithms or threads to hold the first value found then continue looping until it sees the second the print it out. I would appreciate any help possible.

Here is my code:

```
public static void random_sortType(){ 

    types = new ArrayList<String>();
    types.add("Start");
    types.add("Starting");
    types.add("Load");
    types.add("Loading");
    types.add("End");

    ran = new Random();
    int listSize = types.size();
    String tempEventType;//the temp variable intended to hold temporary values
    for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++){ //the loop goes round the ArrayList 10 times 
        int index = ran.nextInt(listSize);//this produces the random selection of the elements within the list
        if(index == 0){
            out.println(types.get(index));
            out.println();
            break;
        }
        if(index == 1){
            tempEventType = types.get(index);
            if(index == 0){
                tempEventType = types.get(0) + " " + types.get(1);
                out.println(tempEventType);             
                break;
            }
        }/*if(index == 0){
            tempEventType = types.get(0) + " " + types.get(1);
            out.println(tempEventType);             
            break;
        }*/

        //out.print("Index is " + index + ": ");
        //out.println(types.get(index));

    }
}
```

Comment: You have if (index == 0) inside if (index ==1). How can that happen?

Comment: @Ryan....Lol yeah, I saw that but left it to give an idea of my mistakes and also maybe help understand what I'm trying to do?

Comment: what I need is using the index values something that when index is 0 print the value & stop, if index is 1 wait until index is 0 then print both values at [0, 1] & stop, if index is 2 wait until index is 1 then print both values at [1, 2] & stop, if index is 3 wait until index is 2 then print both values at [2, 3] & stop, if index is 4 wait until index is 3 then print both values at [3, 4] then stop

Comment: I just went through my question above and discovered it was edited to be much better grammatically but changed completely what I was asking about! I now understand the answers given.

Answer (score 0):

You need to store the  random generated index into a global variable and update it everytime a random number is generated. It should be something like this.

```
    public static void random_sortType(){ 

    types = new ArrayList<String>();
    types.add("Start");
    types.add("Starting");
    types.add("Load");
    types.add("Loading");
    types.add("End");
`   int previousIndex;
    ran = new Random();
    int listSize = types.size();
    String tempEventType;//the temp variable intended to hold temporary values
    for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++){ //the loop goes round the ArrayList 10 times 
        int index = ran.nextInt(listSize);//this produces the random selection of the elements within the list
        previous_index =index;
        if(index == 0){


    out.println(types.get(index));
        out.println();
        break;
    }
    if(index == 1){
        tempEventType = types.get(index);
        if(previousIndex == 0){
            temp EventType = types.get(0) + " " + types.get(1);
                out.println(tempEventType);             
                break;
            }
```

Comment: @kk1992.....I tried your solution though it didn't work, I'm thinking of trying a situation where if previousIndex & index = 0 print value when index is 1 store that in previousIndex until index is 0 then print the values in order [0, 1]. I think that would solve the problem as I would replicate that logic for the rest where when index is 2 store in previousIndex until index is 1 then print values in order of [1, 2]

Answer (score 0):

According to your description, these are the basic requirements for your application:

1. Process ArrayList in random order
2. Processing = printing value at randomly selected index
3. Make 10 attempts to process items in the list.
4. Detect when random index is 1 or 0.
   if  1
       don't process, but flag it was selected.
   if 0 && 1 is flagged
       process 0 and 1
       exit

If these requirements are correct, here is the implementation I came up with:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Random;
import static java.lang.System.*;

public class RandomSort {
    private static final int MAX_ATTEMPTS = 10;
    private static boolean wasOneSelected = false;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ArrayList<String> types = new ArrayList<>(5);
        types.add("Start");
        types.add("Starting");
        types.add("Load");
        types.add("Loading");
        types.add("End");
        random_sortType(types);
    }

    public static void random_sortType(ArrayList<String> types) {
        Random ran = new Random();
        int lastIndex = types.size() - 1; // index range is from 0 to 4
        for (int i = 0; i < MAX_ATTEMPTS; i++) {
            int index = ran.nextInt(lastIndex);
            if ( (index == 0) && wasOneSelected) {
                process(types.get(index) + " " + types.get(index + 1));
                break;
            } else if (index == 1) {
                wasOneSelected = true;
            } else {
                process(types.get(index));
            }
        }
    }

    public static void process(String str) {
        out.println("Processing: " + str);

    }
}
```

The key here is the inclusion of the boolean wasOneSelected initialized to false.  Once it is set to true, it will never be false again for the duration of the application.  The if-else block handles all branching within the loop, and I favored wrapping the println call into a method called "process" for readability purposes to align it more closely with your description.

Feedback appreciated :)

Comment: @Tyrone.....It works only when index is 1 after which it prints out the other values as single strings, what I need is using the index values something that when index is 0 print the value & stop, if index is 1 wait until index is 0 then print both values at [0, 1] & stop, if index is 2 wait until index is 1 then print both values at [1, 2] & stop, if index is 3 wait until index is 2 then print both values at [2, 3] & stop, if index is 4 wait until index is 3 then print both values at [3, 4]..... I see where you are going though :-)